# Playa Just Stopped Working

Tags: playa

A client has just emailed and none of the playa fields are working on the front end templates. No changes have been made to the EE or plugin setup to cause the issue. The site has been up and running for 12 months.

EE is 2.5.5
Playa 4.3.3

For example

```
<ul class="quicklinks">
 {exp:playa:children field="page_quicklinks" limit="7"}
<li><a href="{exp:structure:entries}{quicklink_url}{/exp:structure:entries}">{title}</a></li>
 {/exp:playa:children}
</ul>
```

Outputs

```
<ul class="quicklinks">
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
<li><a href="">Express Orthodontics</a></li>
</ul>
```

"Express Orthodontics" is the current page title not the playa item title

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the [var_prefix parameter](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html) is your friend in this case!

Comment: I'm thinking is might be a PHP version issue. I've just grabbed a full copy of the site and put it on our dev server and there are no issues. The live server is running PHP Version 5.4.26 and the dev server is running PHP Version 5.3.28. But if I upgrade playa to the latest version (4.4.5) on the live site I get "A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'parent_is_draft'

ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_is_draft INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER parent_var_id

Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php

Line Number: 474"

Comment: Haven't seen this in a while! The comment section here ruins all formatting, so here's the solution: http://pastie.org/private/k07xldc2jrtfrdox0asyg

Comment: Thanks Andris. Just did the steps and set the correct Playa version number (4.4.5). Didn't fix my issue unfortunately. Playa fields are still not working in the templates on the live site.

Comment: Are you also using the var_prefix parameter? It is definitely recommended, if you're dealing with Playa tags within an exp:channel:entries loop.

Comment: Hi Andris. I tried the var_prefix, as you suggested, on my original example like this: http://pastie.org/8973037. It worked. I hope I'm doing it right and not setting myself up for another issue. I still have no idea why a site that has worked fine for 12 months would all of a sudden have issues with playa fields and require the var_prefix to work. If anyone can tell me why for my own knowledge, that would be great. Thanks very much for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Mike, it all depends on whether EE parses the {title} during the exp:channel:entries loop or the exp:playa:children loop. I'm not the guru at EE template parsing order here to answer why that happens, that's why our first recommendation always is to use var_prefix, as that makes the template more readable as well.

Comment: thanks for all the advice. will use var_prefix from now one. Still baffled why it all worked fine for 12 months then stopped all of a sudden...